# Regex For Validating Email + Whitelisting Characters

Tags: javascript, java, regex, gmail

I am new to regex and am trying to exclude emails that have special characters with the exception of the dot/period (.) and (@) from being included in my output. Is there something I may be doing wrong perhaps here? Here is what I have:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\.{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\@(?:gmail|GMAIL)([\.])(?:com|COM)
```

My text below is:

hr+team@gmail.com

user.name@gmail.com

second.username@gmail.com

third.username@gmail.com

fourth.username@gmail.com

fifth.username@gmail.com

I am trying to match emails that look like user.name@gmail.com in my output, and exclude emails that are similar to hr+team@gmail.com or any others that have special characters that are not (.) or (@). Please let me know if you can provide any help, thank you!

EDIT: To clarify, how would I grab all of the emails below EXCEPT the first line (hr+team@gmail.com)?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'm asking how I would blacklist certain special characters from my current expression as it is. For example, the emails I listed, I'm wondering how I would exclude that first email, but grab the others.

Comment: It's already doing that.

Comment: @it_enthusiast2022 be more specific. Why do you want to exclude the first one? What is wrong with him? Because he is using the '+' sign? Because the '+' sign is at the middle? Other reasons? If you don't know to express why it should be banned, how we, or your program, will be able to know it should be ban too? What is the meaning of the phrase "looks like"?

Comment: Sorry for a lack of clarity. I'm attempting to exclude any emails like this because they are not user emails. So any emails with a + sign will have to be excluded essentially.. It currently excludes the first 3 characters in hr+, but highlights the rest of team@gmail.com

Comment: Add `^` beginning of the RegEx.
    *`^` asserts position at the start of a line* and
    *`$` asserts position at the end of a line*.
`^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})([\.{1}])?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\@(?:gmail|GMAIL)([\.])(?:com|COM)$`

Comment: Thank you for your response. So currently with that set up, it isn't giving me any results sadly. Since I am just attempting to filter out results/emails that include "+" in them, would this be correct? Again, thank you

Comment: if 1 dot is required in the name, then `/^\w+\.\w+@gmail\.com$/i`. Test [here](https://regex101.com/r/NNGyvo/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be as demonstrated below. In the [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (regex) used below within the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method does contain some limits to what is acceptable as a valid E-Mail address which of course can be changed. They are as follows:

- First Group: `([a-z]{1,10}\\.)?` - The first portion of the E-Mail
  address Username may or may not contain a Start String consisting of all lower
  letter case (a to z) alphabetic characters from 1 to 10 characters in
  length and must be followed by a period (.) character. In this particular regex,   this is considered optional in a valid E-Mail Address.

  If you want to make this Start String an actual requirement then
  simply remove the question mark (?). If you want to change the number
  of characters limits then change the values of **1** and or **10** (1
  being the minimum allowed and 10 being the maximum allowed). If you
  don't can about a maximum then just remove the **10** but leave the
  comma (`{1,}`). If you want to also allow numbers then also place a
  number range within the Square Brackets, for example:
  `([a-z0-9]{1,10}\\.)?`.
- Second Group: `([a-z]){2,10}` - The second portion to the Username of
  the E-Mail Address is mandatory and must consist of only lower letter
  case alphabetic characters from **a** to **z**. The can only be a
  minimum of **2** characters in this name and a maximum of **10**
  character. These limits can of course be changed to suit your needs
  (read the bullet above to find out how).
- `\\@` - The **At Sign** is mandatory and must be provided to be a
  valid E-Mail Address. Only one can be within an E-Mail Address and
  ***must*** be following by a domain name (see next bullet).
- Third Group: `(gmail.com|ymail.com|yahoo.com|hotmail.com)` - The
  allowable Domain Names that can be within a valid E-Mail Address. Any
  domain name other than any one of those listed will be considered an
  Invalid E-Mail Address to the regex provided. You can add more
  domains names if you like as long as each is separated with the Pipe
  ( **|** ) character (regex OR).

```
// However way you want to fill an String[] array of E-Mail Adresses:
String[] addresses = {"hr+team@gmail.com", "user.name@hotmail.com",
                      "second.username@gmail.com", "third.username@yahoo.com",
                      "fourth.username@gmail.com", "fifth.username@gmail.com"};

for (String addy : addresses) {
    if (addy.matches("([a-z]{1,10}\\.)?([a-z]){2,10}\\@(gmail.com|ymail.com|yahoo.com|hotmail.com)")) {
        System.out.printf("E-Mail Address:  %-28s is Valid!%n", addy);
    }
    else {
        System.out.printf("E-Mail Address:  %-28s is NOT Valid!%n", addy);
    }
}
```

Console window should display:

```
E-Mail Address:  hr+team@gmail.com            is NOT Valid!
E-Mail Address:  user.name@hotmail.com        is Valid!
E-Mail Address:  second.username@gmail.com    is Valid!
E-Mail Address:  third.username@yahoo.com     is Valid!
E-Mail Address:  fourth.username@gmail.com    is Valid!
E-Mail Address:  fifth.username@gmail.com     is Valid!
```

Comment: This helped out A LOT. Thank you so much. One last question - if one of the emails followed the format of firstl@gmail.com in that list as well, what would I need to change to ensure that those can be selected as well while still excluding the one above? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean as a valid or invalid address? As a valid address, nothing. To the provided regex, that is a valid E-Mail Address. To see it as Invalid, remove the question mark (?) within the regex (as is already explained within the answer above). If in doubt, add it to the array of addresses to find out. On a side: if you have found this question helpful then don't forget to select it as *useful*.